# Initializer-string for array of chars is too long for char[]

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constexpr

I have this struct in my code:

```
struct Foo {
    // more stuff but not important
    char key[];
};

constexpr Foo foo[] = {
    { "something" }
};
```

and GCC compiler throws this error:

> error: initializer-string for array of chars is too long
>   [-fpermissive]

Any ideas why? or how it can be solved?

Comment: `char key[];` doesn't have a size, so how long is it? And anyway, different `Foo`s cannot have different sizes.

Comment: You should probably use `std::string` instead of char arrays. You're writing in C++ not in C.

Comment: @mihai pop  Show code that generates this error.

Comment: If for some reason you really really have to use char arrays, then define key as pointer to char, as usual with dynamic arrays. But most likely you don't have good reasons to use char arrays over strings. If you need to feed a char array to something, like initializing a stream from iostream, there is `string::c_str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The auto-sizing of the last element is not standard c++. The standard allows you to declare that zero-length array, and it is for the obvious use-case, but does not say how to get it allocated the size you want.

Some compilers do support it in some ways as an extension.

To do it cleanly in pre-template days required a custom allocator operator new. These days you might for example wrap it in a derived template instance class which actually does the sizing as a template argument - you could return that from a template function that deduces the array size. The base array is then legal to use.

Answer (score 4):

The warning shows an issue with the `key` variable which is a flexible type (in terms of length). Such definition is fine as long as the variable is the last member. Depending on your compiler version and flags this might be a warning or error. I believe it was considered a gcc bug and described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68613).

The simplest fix to make the warning go away is to put a fixed value for the char array like so:

```
struct Foo {
    char key[10];
};

constexpr Foo foo[] = {
    {"something"}
};
std::cout<<foo[0].key; // prints out 'something'
```

However, note one more thing. You are trying to create an array of `Foo` objects. In your current implementation it means that each object will have the same `key` array length.

If you want this to change between objects you should go for `std::string`